# Compose multiple promises into one promise PlayFramework 2.4

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0, promise

I am trying to learn the Play Framework 2.4. I am trying to get the time it takes to access different webpages asynchronously using Promise. Below is the code for that:

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

F.Function<WSResponse,Long> timing = new F.Function<WSResponse, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long apply(WSResponse wsResponse) throws Throwable {
        return System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
    }
};
F.Promise<Long> google = ws.url("http://www.google.com").get().map(timing);
F.Promise<Long> yahoo = ws.url("http://www.yahoo.com").get().map(timing);
F.Promise<Long> bing = ws.url("http://www.bing.com").get().map(timing);
```

As you can see I am using the get function to get the requested pages and putting the result in a Future Promise. Then I convert/map it to long. What I am not able to do is how do I compose these three promises into one and once all of the three promises are redeemed convert/map it to json and return the result. In earlier versions of Play it could have been done by `F.Promise.waitAll(google,yahoo,bing).map(...)` however I am unable to do it in Play 2.4. Please advice

**EDIT1**: Based on the answer below i used sequence like below:

```
return F.Promise.sequence(google, yahoo, bing).map(new F.Function<List<Long>, Result>() {
            @Override
            public Result apply(List<Long> longs) throws Throwable {
                Map<String, Long> data = new HashMap<String, Long>();
                data.put("google", google.get());
                data.put("yahoo", yahoo.get());
                data.put("bing", bing.get());
                return ok(Json.toJson(data));
            }
        });
```

However, i am getting error that google.get() method cannot be resolved and that Json cannot be applied. What am i missing here?

**EDIT 2.** The Json error was fixed by using `return ok((JsonNode) Json.toJson((Writes<Object>) data));` However, i am still not able to resolve the earlier error that google.get() method cannot be resolved in the line `data.put("google", google.get());`

**EDIT 3.** It seems Play2.4 has no get() method which returns the value of a Promise once it has been redeemed. What should i use then?

Comment: Are you using `play.api.libs.Json` or `play.libs.Json`? If you're writing in Java, you should be using the latter but it looks like you're using the Scala library.  Any play package containing `api` is part of the Scala API.

Comment: See my example below. You shouldn't be using the promises once you've passed them into .sequence - that's the whole point of mapping the response! The List passed into `.map` is of type `List<Long>`.

Comment: i am using play.libs.Json...I figured that out... :) thanks for your help

Comment: I've updated my example to be a complete example, including imports.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`waitAll` has been replaced with `F.Promise.sequence`.

From the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html#sequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

`public static <A> F.Promise<java.util.List<A>> sequence(java.lang.Iterable<F.Promise<A>> promises)`

> Combine the given promises into a single promise for the list of results. The sequencing operations are performed in the default ExecutionContext.
>
> Parameters:
>   promises - The promises to combine
>
> Returns:
>   A single promise whose methods act on the list of redeemed promises

**Update**

Regarding the second half of the question, you don't need to call `.get()` because the promises have already completed.

In fact, you can get rid of the individual promise variables and just pass them directly into the sequence.  The resulting list will contain results in the same order (Google first, then Yahoo, then Bing, in this case).

The whole thing should look something like this:

```
package controllers;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.Json;
import play.libs.ws.WS;
import play.libs.ws.WSResponse;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.mvc.Results;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public F.Promise<Result> index() {
        final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final F.Function<WSResponse,Long> timing = response -> System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        return F.Promise.sequence(WS.url("http://www.google.com").get().map(timing),
                                  WS.url("http://www.yahoo.com").get().map(timing),
                                  WS.url("http://www.bing.com").get().map(timing))
                        .map(list -> {
                            Map<String, Long> data = new HashMap<>();
                            data.put("google", list.get(0));
                            data.put("yahoo", list.get(1));
                            data.put("bing", list.get(2));
                            return data;
                        })
                        .map(Json::toJson)
                        .map(Results::ok);
    }

}
```

Finally, since Play 2.4 requires Java 8, this is a good opportunity to play around with lambdas!

Comment: Thanks a lot...I am now using sequence. however i am getting a couple of errors. have updated the question. Will try to look into them. Thanks... The tutorials at the official Play site are not that descriptive and most of the examples and tutorials belong to earlier versions. Thanks for guindg the way.

Comment: I tried your answer...However i am getting a Cyclic Inference error on the line `.map(json -> ok(json));`

Comment: It's interesting that they went from the JavaScript/C# (`.all` and `.WhenAll`) name of the operator to the Haskell name of the operator (`sequence`). I wonder why. Anyway, good answer.

Comment: @200ok it works for me, but try the updated version above - it uses method references instead of lambdas.

Comment: This works...i still do not understand why the earlier one was not working...I was indeed using play.libs.Json... Anyways, thanks a lot for your time and effort. i truly appreciate it. I will also try to look why the earlier one was not working and if i find anything i will update as an Edit. thanks